# Default ForegroundColor of StatusBar depending on Theme

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, statusbar

I am looking for the default `ForegroundColor` (or resource key) of the `StatusBar` in the *Light* or *Dark* Theme. I need to set the `ForegroundColor` manually because it seems to be not updated according to the `RequestedTheme`.

If I set the `RequestedTheme` in my app to *Light* and the `SystemTheme` is *Dark*, the `StatusBar` will be displayed with white `ForegroundColor`. I expected that the `ForegroundColor` of the `StatusBar` depends on the App's `RequestedTheme`.

Answer (score 0):

The only known way to change the StatusBar colors so far is by doing it in C#. No XAML resources to override unfortunately.
You can change the StatusBar colors like so:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor = Colors.Black;
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
```

Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView() has more properties btw.

If you want to be able to change the colors depending on which theme is requested, you could check for the requested theme:

```
if( Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Light )
{
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor = Colors.Black;
    Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
}
```

Comment: I know this already, but I need to know the exactly foreground color and opacity of the statusbar in light/dark theme.

Comment: Do you mean the XAML resource or the actual color? If you mean the XAML resource than there is none available to (third-party) developers as far as I know. If you mean the color, you can just use var color = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor.

Comment: Yes, I mean the XAML resource of these colors. I thought that there are resources available. Do you know why the color of the StatusBar depends on the SystemTheme and not on the Application's RequestedTheme?

Comment: I really wish I did, I've struggled with the same issue.

Comment: I cannot use var color = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ForegroundColor because it is null.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought if one doesn't assign it a value, it'll have the default value. But may I ask why you need to "get" the default? The light theme uses white as the background color and black as the foreground color and the opposite is used for the dark theme.

Comment: Yes, I know that they are simply white and black colors, but I think they also use the alpha-channel to appear a little bit transparent and I want to extactly the same appearance.

Comment: I would also like to know this because you're right that changing the status bar color simply to black or white only closely resembles default colors and is not an exact match.

Comment: Interestingly enough on this page it says: "The alpha channel of the color is not used."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar.foregroundcolor